# Negative Reputation breaks keyboard shortcut menu in Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

When having a negative reputation change, The negative reputation is added to the menu item to navigate to reputation and breaks the menu of the shortcut menu in Profile. Having a positive reputation change, is not display in the menu.

I think the negative reputation change is too much and should not be displayed

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it shouldn't. Fixed in the next build.